# jQuery: after() in loop results in reverse order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with html tags as strings in it such as :

```
array = [
"<p>1</p>",
"<p>2</p>",
"<p>3</p>"
]
```

and a for loop that uses the after() method :

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  $(this).after(array[i])
}
```

Which results in "3 2 1" instead of "1 2 3" as I expected. Is there a method like after() that put the html tag below the previously placed one? Are there any ways to achieve what I'm trying to do? Thanks you, have a nice day :)

Comment: Can you stick the array together and use after on the joined array?  `$(this).after(array.join(""))` ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the reversed order: Initially you add `1` after `$(this)`, then you add `2`, etc. Each time the content that exists after `$(this)` gets pushed down, hence the reverse order.

jQuery `.after()` docs: *Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.*

That is, you can supply the whole array at once, and it will be in the proper order:

```
$(this).after(array)
```